# Web app needs to communicate with serial port

Tags: java, php, javascript, cross-platform, serial-port

I'm writing an application that needs access to a serial port (it's a credit card reader). I'd like to be able to read and write to the port. The following seems like it would let me do exactly that: http://www.activexperts.com/serial-port-component/howto/html/. However, this deals with ActiveX/COM which means I'm tied to Windows.

Any better solutions for me? Would be nice if the solution would work on multiple platforms, not just Windows.

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Did the reader come with any utility software to drive it?  If there's a commandline utility that can do the work of processing input from the device then you may be better off simply exec()ing it from PHP and collecting the results from stdout.

Comment: If you're using php, why is this tagged 'java' ?

Comment: @GordonM - I'm still waiting on the hardware, but the provider did mention that ActiveX/COM solution.

Comment: @JoeriHendrickx - it's tagged Java since I'm hoping for a cross platform solution. That's also why I tagged it "cross platform"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the device emulate a keyboard?  You'd be much better off getting the user to position the cursor inside a textbox (or putting the cursor there programmatically) and swiping the card if that's the case.

I spent a lot of time writing a userspace driver in C for a [Magtek Mini-Mag](http://www.hallogram.com/barcodes/scanners/mag/) card reader only to realize years later that it was academic more than anything.  I mean we used the code, only if we'd have gone with the keyboard solution there would have been tons of time to focus on other things.

For the Mini-Mag the [USB/HID support](http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x194.html) in the kernel would recognize the device, hopefully there's something similar for the device you're getting.

Also, Windows has it's own variant of USB/HID so the 'treat it as a keyboard' solution works pretty much out of the box for devices that act that way.