# Accessing client devices from a webapp

Tags: java, php, web-applications, client-side

I have been looking for an answer for this question for days, but I can't seem to find anything concrete.

I have a number of clients who I have made e-commerce websites for.  I want to make a point of sale system that integrates perfectly with my e-commerce systems (so that inventory, customers, sales data ect. are kept consistent throughout both systems). I want the POS to be web based, and accessible from anywhere, and any device (so that inventory can be taken on laptop, or sales can be made away from the store on an ipad for example).

Since this is a web based application, and browsers are sandboxed, what would be the best way to enable my POS to access devices on the clients computer.  I want it to be able to handle a recipe printer, a card scanner and signature capture devices, cash drawers, and customer displays.  It needs to print receipts automatically at the end of each transaction with out prompting a dialog box.  Also the cash drawer needs to open independently from the printer.

The main goal of this project is to keep the POS as flexible as possible.  I want it to be able to operate on any platform, with pretty much any devices, without having to install anything. I will be setting up the POS on the main terminals so it will be possible to install Java or a browser plugin to include this functionality which isn't necessarily needed anywhere but the main terminal (but if possible that would be great!).

What is the best way to implement this without coding everything twice?  Will a plug-in give me the access I need? I looked at Pepper and NaCl, but I am still not sure if that is what I am looking for?  I could probably do this with active-x, but I don't want to be limited to IE.  I saw that silverlight might be able to do this, but I would like to keep it opensource.  I am now thinking about building it in php and adapting it to use quercus on a signed java applet?

Has anyone ever done anything like this and what do yall think would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

For the card reader at least, most of them emulate a keyboard, so for that you simply have the cursor positioned in a text input and then swipe the card.  The OS will treat the swipe as if someone had typed the information on the card into the input.  As for the other devices I'd investigate simliar arrangements where you don't need a custom driver.

A bit redundant, but have a peak at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9359360/web-app-needs-to-communicate-with-serial-port/9359682#9359682) I commented on the other day.

Comment: I know a lot of the bar code scanners a like that as well.  I am more worried about the drawer control, the customer display, and the printer....